# In jsp how we compare string value in If condition

Tags: jsp

We can write

```
if (usermailid != null)
```

It is working but

```
if (usermailid =="Ram")
```

is not working .

Comment: You can use expression language to compare strings (yes it works with strings!), just like this: ${usermailid == "Ram"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brijesh pointed out, `==` checks equality and you should use `equals` as outlined extensively in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/660848).

More efficiently, you could combine null check and check against value in one expression, like so

```
if ("Ram".equals(usermailid)) { /* ... */ }
```

The `equals` check fails if the value is null too, so you don't have to check both in seperate conditions and don't run the risk of `NullPointerException`s.

Also consider extracting the string being tested against as a constant, if it's used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (usermailid.equals("Ram"))
```

this will check the equality.

`==` will compare the reference of both objects which is not same.

For you Reference to JAVA string functions, refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)